# Styles in a progress bar

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems to set up styles on my progressive bar...

The problem I have is that I can't position the image over the corner.

What is the best solution?

Here is my reference design:

[image: here its my reference design]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .progress {
        border-radius: 0px;
        border: 2px solid brown;
        height: 38px;
        position: relative;
      }
      img {
        position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="progress">
            <img src="./corner.png" />
            <div
              data-percentage="0%"
              class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"
              role="progressbar"
              aria-valuemin="0"
              aria-valuemax="100"
              style="width: 10%"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can think of is assigning each corner their own class.

You can see I made a class to manage the image attributes (`progress-corner`) and each progress corner (progress bottom right `pbr`, progress bottom left `pbl`, progress top right `ptr`, and progres top left `ptl`) their location attributes independently. This leaves you with the ability to modify the image once instead of several times / is cleaner code.

I've also added `z-index` in there so it sits on top of other elements.

```css
.progress {
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 2px solid brown;
  height: 38px;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-corner {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c2/c3/17/c2c317b76054b9488ddad2370a7c2266.jpg");
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}

.pbr {
  right: 14px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.ptr {
  right: 14px;
  top: 0;
}

.pbl {
  left: 14px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.ptl {
  left: 14px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="progress">
          <div data-percentage="0%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-corner pbr"></div>
        <div class="progress-corner ptr"></div>
        <div class="progress-corner pbl"></div>
        <div class="progress-corner ptl"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```